# Debian does not detect serial PCI card after reboot

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel-modules, serial-port

I have installed a PCI card with two serial and one parallel port on it. the chipset is `MCS9865`. I downloaded the latest driver(V1.0.12) from [here](http://www.asix.com.tw/FrootAttach/driver/MCS9865_Linux_driver_v1.0.0.12.zip). I ran `make` and `make install`. now the two serial ports are `/dev/ttyD0` and `/dev/ttyD1`. I have tested them with `picocom` and it is working perfectly. the problem is that when I reboot the system there is no `/dev/ttyD0` and `/dev/ttyD1`. I need to do another `make install`. Is there any solution?

output of `lspci -v` shows this:

```
03:01.0 Serial controller: NetMos Technology PCI 9865 Multi-I/O Controller (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Device a000:1000
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at df00 [size=8]
    Memory at fbeff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fbefe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: mcs9865-serial

03:01.1 Serial controller: NetMos Technology PCI 9865 Multi-I/O Controller (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Device a000:1000
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at de00 [size=8]
    Memory at fbefd000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fbefc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: mcs9865-serial

03:01.2 Parallel controller: NetMos Technology PCI 9865 Multi-I/O Controller (prog-if 03 [IEEE1284])
    Subsystem: Device a000:2000
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 7
    I/O ports at dd00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=8]
    Memory at fbefb000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fbefa000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
```

`make install` shows this:

```
cp mcs9865.ko mcs9865-isa.ko /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/serial/
depmod -A
chmod +x mcs9865
cp mcs9865 /etc/init.d/
ln -s /etc/init.d/mcs9865 /etc/rcS.d/S99mcs9865 || true
ln: creating symbolic link `/etc/rcS.d/S99mcs9865': File exists
modprobe mcs9865
modprobe mcs9865-isa
```

I'm running debian 6.0.5 with most updated packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way this normally works is:

- The module source code contains calls to the [`MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE`](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-12-sect-1#chp-12-sect-1.4) macro to declare a table of device identifiers that this module supports.
- In the compiled module, the aliases are stored as values of symbols called `__mod_alias_NNN` where the NNN are integers. The value encodes the bus identification for the device, e.g. `pci:v00009710d00009865sv*sd*bc*sc*i*` for the PCI device identified as [vendor 0x9710](http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendor_details.php?id=1660), device 0x9865.
   <sub>They are also stored under the name `__mod_pci_device_table` for PCI devices, `__mod_usb_device_table` for USB devices, etc.</sub>
- The [`depmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/depmod) program creates an alias table mapping `__mod_alias_NNN` values to the module name. This table is stored in the file `modules.alias` at the root of the kernel modules directory, e.g. `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/modules.alias`.
   <sub>It also creates files like `modules.pcimap`, `modules.usbmap`, …, which are used by the obsolete hotplug infrastructure which has been subsumed back into modprobe.</sub>
- When the kernel detects a device for which no driver is present, it tries to load a module by calling the program indicated by the `kernel.modprobe` [sysctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl), which is [`/sbin/modprobe`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/depmod) by default. The kernel passes an argument to `modprobe` that indicates what driver is requested. For a PCI device, this is a name like `pci:v00009710d00009865sv*sd*bc*sc*i*`.
- `modprobe` searches for a module with the given name. If it finds a module with the requested name (after following the alias defined in its configuration files, which include `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` and `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias`), it loads that module.
  `modprobe` will not load a module that has been blacklisted by a `blacklist` directive in its configuration files.

Run `lspci -n` to see the PCI ids of your device, and check the chain above to see where something went wrong.

Sometimes a driver works for a device that is very similar to the device it is intended for, but has a different PCI id. In that case, it's possible that the driver will work, but won't be loaded automatically because it doesn't declare the PCI id for your device. You can add the alias manually in `/etc/modprobe/my_aliases.conf`.

You can force a module to be loaded automatically at boot time by adding its name to `/etc/modules`.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix would be to run after every reboot

```
modprobe mcs9865
modprobe mcs9865-isa
```

to me it seems as if the kernel modules are not auto inserting.

there is an init script so you might just have to add it to the default run level with this

```
sudo update-rc.d mcs9865 defaults
```