# Pushing changes to driver repos

Tags: drivers, devices, udev, hot-plug

My *understanding* of `dkms` is that its a way to dynamically manage all connected/disconnected device drivers on a Linux system. If that's correct, then I have to imagine that it allows you to configure a "repo" where device drivers can get installed, so that as soon as a hotpluggable device is connected to it, it finds that device's driver (in this repo) and loads it.

If that's correct, then **where is this repo and is that location configurable?** Can it be configured to look for drivers in a remote location (using HTTP, TCP, etc.)?

Also, **does dkms, offer a way to dynamically update/upgrade device drivers at runtime?** It would be nice to push device driver updates to this repo and then have dkms automatically release/unload the driver, overwrite the old driver with the new/updated one, and then reload that new driver.

Comment: I don't believe udev has much to do with device drivers.  I believe it only manages device events and device names in some cases.  Device drivers can be dynamically loaded with dkms, which is different from udev. I suggest you read `man udev` and `man dkms`.

Comment: Thanks @jayhendren (I'd upvote you if I had the rep to do so) - I appreciate the heads up, and I have modified the question to reflect your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Neither [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) nor [DKMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) can be adequately described as “a way to dynamically manage all connected/disconnected device drivers on a Linux system”. Udev dynamically manages *devices*, not drivers — it creates entries in `/dev` when a device is plugged in. DKMS is about drivers, but it has nothing to do with locating a driver for a device: it's a way to compile third-party drivers from source when installing a kernel.

When the kernel detects a device for which no driver is present, it calls the program [`modprobe`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe) to attempt to load a module that provides this driver. The `modprobe` program in turn consults a database created by [`depmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/depmod) which traverses module files (`*.ko`) located under `/lib/modules/VERSION/`. See [debian does not detect serial PCI card after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43699/debian-does-not-detect-serial-pci-card-after-reboot/43723#43723) for a more detailed description of this mechanism.

A nominal sequence of events when a device is connected and no driver is present in memory is:

1. The kernel invokes `modprobe` to load a driver.
2. `modprobe` loads a module file from `/lib/modules`.
3. Now that a driver is available, the kernel notifies udev that a new device is present.
4. udev creates an entry under `/dev` for the new device.

There is no standard mechanism to download a device driver from somewhere when an unknown device is detected. The normal way to install drivers is to have all possible drivers installed on your system, provided by your distribution — it isn't always possible to download drivers (e.g. when you need the driver to connect to the network, or you don't have a network connection). Upgrading drivers works the same way as upgrading anything else, by upgrading the package that contains the driver file (which is often the kernel package).

DKMS intervenes when a driver is not part of the Linux kernel. It is hard to make a module binary that works across kernel versions and compilation options. DKMS is a framework to automatically compile modules for the installed kernel(s); the modules are distributed as source code.