# Running a program after system startup directly from the linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I am trying to run my application directly from the linux kernel (without using cron or something similar). I've tried using `./init/init.c`, but it runs too early:

```
$ dmesg 

...
[    0.605657] TEST!!!
...
```

My idea is to launch an application after successful user login, but I cannot find an appropriate function to use.

Comment: Did you change the kernel's source for your test?  Should this program be run on every login?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want it after the user logs in you can put it in your shell profile file.  Most likely `~/.bash_profile`.

You want to add a line,  probably near the end, that simply calls the filename of your application as if you were running it from your terminal, for example: `/home/username/bin/mypersonalscript.sh&`.  You may need to use the absolute path.

Also be sure to add the ampersand to the end.  That forks the process to the background and without it you may not be able to get into your shell when you log in.

If it doesn't work, make sure your script is executable.

Comment: `.bashrc` is invoked every time the user starts a shell (e.g. typing `:sh` inside `vi`).  If you want once per login then `.bash_profile` is a better place.  (Or `.profile` if using `ksh` or `sh` as the shell; or `.login` if using `csh` or `tcsh`).

Comment: You're right of course. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The job of the kernel is to run one process: [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), which gets process ID 1. It's init's job to run other processes to provide system services and allow users to log in.

There are a few other cases where the Linux kernel will execute a process. For example, when the kernel detects new hardware on certain buses, it [executes `modprobe` to load a driver as a module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43699/debian-does-not-detect-serial-pci-card-after-reboot/43723#43723). Another example is that it's possible to configure a program to pipe core dumps through. I think all of these cases use the [`call_usermodehelper_xxx`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=4.5;i=call_usermodehelper_exec) functions.

You'll note that there are only very few cases, and they're all triggered by a kernel event: hardware event or program termination. These are exceptional cases, reserved for low-level system functionality. The normal way to execute a process is that it's forked from a process that's forked from a process that's … that's forked from init.

The kernel doesn't even *know* about a “successful login”. Logging in is a high-level concept, well above the kernel. To run a process as root when a user logs in, add it to the [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) configuration, with the [`pam_exec`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html) module. To run a process as the user who logged in, add it to the user's shell startup file, typically `~/.profile`.