# Error setting up a new xfs file system: unknow fs type

Tags: debian, sysvinit, xfs

I am trying to setup a new xfs filesystem in Debian 9/stretch. My kernel version is 4.9.0-3-amd64.

For that I installed the package `xfsprogs`, and initialised the new partition with:

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1
```

I also defined the `/etc/fstab` line to mount it as:

```
/dev/sdb1   /srv      xfs   defaults    0   2
```

However, when trying to mount it, either with `mount -a` or `mount /srv`, it does not mount, and gives back the following error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'xfs'
```

As I noticed the post-install scripts of `xfsprogs` had regenerated the `initrd` file, I took the shortcut of rebooting the server, with pretty much the same results.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to `/etc/modules` the xfs module, so in the next boot it will be loaded as in:

```
xfs
```

Also, to load it in runtime do:

```
sudo modprobe xfs
```

After that, `mount -a` worked and mounted the `/srv` partition successfully.

To double-check it is mounted:

```
$ mount -t xfs
/dev/sdb1 on /srv type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

The partition was also mounted automatically after a reboot, and it can be check the `xfs` module was loaded:

```
$lsmod | grep xfs
xfs                  1208320  1
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. The kernel is capable of loading filesystem driver modules automatically.

Comment: @Gilles I suspected so. Will have to have a look at that initrd, I think

Comment: The initrd shouldn't matter. Having `xfs.ko` in the initrd is only necessary if the root filesystem is xfs. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43699/debian-does-not-detect-serial-pci-card-after-reboot/43723#43723) is the general process for automatic module loading. In your case one of the steps fails. Check `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias` and the system logs.

Comment: @Gilles That dawned me later on, thanks. Will have to do some testing in my standard VM.